# Devide audio signal into small samples

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to process an audio signal and divide an audio signal into N discrete samples and then I want to play that samples independently.

How can I do this using python?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "matlab"?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Try to write it yourself and when you run into problems that you can't solve with google, post the problem and your code.

Comment: import wave
import math
w = wave.open('song1.wav', 'r')

fs = 11000; # sampling frequency
frame_duration = 0.04;
frame_len = frame_duration*fs;
N = 40000;
num_frames= int(math.floor(N/frame_len));
#print num_frames

for i in range(1,num_frames):
    
    frame = w.readframes(1)

Comment: @  Brian Keller-Heikkila i tried this. but how can i get frequency within each frame

Comment: @BirunthaG can you put your code in your post and not in the comment? Hard to read ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import wave
 import pygame
 import time



def slice(infile, outfilename, start_ms, end_ms):
    width = infile.getsampwidth() #Returns sample width in bytes
    rate = infile.getframerate()  #Returns sampling frequency
    fpms = rate / 1000 # frames per ms
    length = (end_ms - start_ms) * fpms
    start_index = start_ms * fpms

    out = wave.open(outfilename, "w")
    out.setparams((infile.getnchannels(), width, rate, length, infile.getcomptype(), infile.getcompname()))

    infile.rewind()             #Rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the audio stream
    anchor = infile.tell()      #Return current file pointer position
    infile.setpos(anchor + start_index)  #Set the file pointer to the specified position
    out.writeframes(infile.readframes(length)) #Write audio frames and make sure nframes is correct


if __name__ == "__main__":

     slice(wave.open("song1.wav", "r"), "out.wav", 500, 5000)

     pygame.mixer.init()
     pygame.mixer.music.load("out.wav")
     pygame.mixer.music.play()
     while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
           continue
```